# Is it possible to remove unlock_time for a transaction?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-unlock-time

Is there any way to remove unlock_time for a sent transaction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You need overwrite the transaction with another transaction sans unlock_time. If the transaction in question is already in a block, then you'll need to reorganize the blockchain to the depth where this transaction was first added, removing it and adding your replacement.

The short version: "no". This is part of the immutability property of blockchains (unless you are ETH).

Comment: So really the second way to do it is to convince a majority of miners and nodes that they're *Doing the Right Thing* and *Thinking of the Children* by ignoring the unlock time on your transaction.

Comment: My future children will probably be happy if I lock up some monero for them. Good to know I have to be real careful playing around with the unlock_time :)